# Sitecore item name not accepting more than 100 characters

Tags: sitecore-client, content-editor

[image]I am using sitecore 9.1 initial release and i created an item and gave the item name above 100 characters but sitecore is not accepting the item name more that 100  charaters , so in the sitecore.config file i change the `<setting name="MaxItemNameLength" value="100" />` to 200 , 256 and even 1000 , but still item name is not accepting more that 100 characters . I checked the showconfig also , and the values are reflecting there also .

Comment: What do you mean by "item name is not accepting more than 100 characters"? Do you see some popup with message, is the input only allowing 100 chars, are there exceptions in the log file?

Comment: there is no exception in the log files , yes there is a popup which shows the name i entered is invalid ,but when i removed some characters from the end , then it is saving the item.Added the image in the edit

Comment: Can you shorten the name and use the display name for the longer version?

Comment: Likely you are using ' characters in the name. That will cause rejection. e.g. `battle against Trump's administration`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From what I know when you try to use item name which is longer than `MaxItemNameLength` setting, e.g.:

```
<setting name="MaxItemNameLength" value="100" />
```

The message that is shown is

> The length of the value is too long.
>
> Please specify a value of less than 100 characters.

[image]

The message which you see:

> 'Your name' is not a valid name.

is displayed when the item name you're trying to use doesn't match the regex specified in the `ItemNameValidation` setting, e.g.

```
<setting name="ItemNameValidation" value="^\\w[\\w\\s]*$" />
```

Check that setting in your `showconfig.aspx` and make sure the new name matches the regex.

Comment: Thanks @marek this worked like a charm